# What are the chemical contents of beef stock?

Tags: beef, stock

I am familiar with the average beef stock recipe. After the liquid is strained, what are its chemical contents, exactly? Is it just water + denatured animal cell proteins? Does it contain collagen? What would I see if I looked at it under an electron microscope?

Comment: You'd see nothing useful if you used an EM on beef stock.

Comment: This question is not about cooking.

Comment: Of course it’s about cooking. Understanding the chemical makeup of a food can help you understand how to work with it.

Comment: Most cooks don't have an electron microscope to hand @Sneftel

Comment: @GdD ... not sure I get your point?

Comment: While there is no rule against the chemical contents of a food, they also have to be focused enough. Beef stock can contain everything that is in beef - so we are talking about hundreds of different compounds here, too much for a single question.

Comment: There seems to be inconsistent rationales on which this question is being rejected as a "off-topic" question, which makes me want to know the answer even more. Is there a different Q/A website I could ask this question on instead?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a good number of scientific papers on what's in beef broth.

I'd say, take all this with a grain of salt (pun) and enjoy your cup of broth as is.

Minerals : https://honey-guide.com/2014/01/21/bone-broth-mineral-content/

Amino acids : https://www.westmont.edu/sites/default/files/users/user1231/V19No4/Nick%20Flynn_final.pdf

Collagen(ish) : https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29893587/

Collagen : https://journals.humankinetics.com/view/journals/ijsnem/29/3/article-p265.xml

"Bone Broth Unlikely to Provide Reliable Concentrations of Collagen Precursors Compared With Supplemental Sources of Collagen Used in Collagen Research"